# Getting table specific columns after joining the tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, inner-join

I've 3 tables lets say **A**, **B**, and **C**. And they have common fields **created_date** which are table specific.

If I join the tables with left join using id's, then how can I get like, **A.created_date** after fetching the records in the view page while displaying the result. I mean if I use $row->created_date it will fetch me some other tables records or 01-01-1970 which is useless.

Comment: Hey @prabhu first check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

 then post questions.

Comment: Add alias `A.created_date as a_created_date`,`b.created_date as b_created_date` etc and use it as `$row->a_created_date`

Comment: try using alias: A.created_date AS a_created_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering why the desired result was not displayed. I'm thankful to @naim malek for the clue. Tried searching more solutions from the web. This worked for me.

```
$query_selection = "a.created_date as first_created_date, a.userid as first_userid, b.accountid as sec_accountid";
$data = array('a.userid'=>$userid);

$this->db->select($query_selection);
$this->db->from($table); 
if($data!=NULL){
    $this->db->where($data);
}
$result_set = $this->db->get();
if($result_set->num_rows() > 0){
    return $result_set->result();
}
else {
    return FALSE;
}
```